# Why i am getting this error while connection my java program to sql server

Tags: java, sql

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at demo.main(demo.java:19)
```

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: You're using the wrong version of the JDBC driver jar file. Since you're running with Java 8, add `mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre8.jar` to the classpath, not `mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre11.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

Your drivers claims to be compiled using Java 11, whereas you are using an *older* version of Java. You need to upgrade your JRE/JDK to version 11.

Comment: Or use a Java 8 version of the JDBC driver. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951911/why-i-am-getting-this-error-while-connection-my-java-program-to-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment96666883_54951911).